# General large input test. Hexadecimal arrays in C++11

Tags: c++11, hex

> Almost all my input parameters work except for some larger number inputs for my hexadecimal addition program. My program asks user to input two numbers and it would give out the sum of the two numbers. However, the number should be only 10 digits long, and if it exceeds 10 digits it should output an Addition Overflow.
>
> > 1. If I input "1" for first number and "ffffffffff" (10 digits) for my second number I would get an output of "Addition Overflow.". (Correct)
> > 2. However, if my first number were to be a "0" and second number to still be "ffffffffff" I would get an "Addition Overflow." which is incorrect. The output should still be "ffffffffff"

Comment: `if(digits > length - 1)` This checks whether the result exceeds 9 digits, not 10 as in your problem statement. You pass `length==10`, so therefore `length-1 == 9`

Comment: If I set ' if(digits > length + 1)', it would print out 1 + ffffffffff = 10000000000

Comment: same with just `if(digits > length)`

Comment: Because you don't account for the last carry in `digits`. You always have `digits == m` (not clear why you even bother counting) - but the result of addition may be one digit longer than `m`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not an experienced coder. I am a bit confused. So would I change my logic in finding the length of the number?

Comment: `if (m + c > length) return true;`, and drop `digits`

Comment: I've added that, changed `for (i  = m + c; i >= 0; i--)`, and dropped `digits` but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Ah, of course. You are changing `m`, it's 0 by the end of the function. Make it `int digits  = m;` at the top; don't touch `digits` anymore. Keep the loop as before, `for(i = digits; i >= 0; i--)`; and the check would be `if (digits + c > length)`. [Like this](http://rextester.com/EVY55142)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take the final carry, and shift everything over in this loop:

```
if (c != 0){
for(i = digits; i >= 0; i--)
  answer[i] = answer[i-1];
answer[0] = hex[c];
}
```

You need to increment digits by one, as you have now added another digit at the end.

Then you need to change this statement:

```
if(digits > length - 1)
```

to this statement:

```
if(digits > length)
```

That will fix your problem.